# Import library from /usr/local to PyCharm

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I have installed OpenCV and make a python virtual environment adding a simbolink link to OpenCV library in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/sites-packages/cv2.so
This is working fine (in Spyder I only change the default interpreter by the interpreter in the virtual environment and the library is loaded). 
But when I do the same thing in PyCharm, it seems like the simbolink link is broken because PyCharm can't acces to /usr/local... path ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ9N4.png)).

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm, you can go to the settings from the file menu. Under the project settings, go to the project interpreter. Choose the project interpreter you want from the list of options. From the list you can see the modules loaded for the interpreter in the virtual environment. If you find any library missing, you can just add them by searching for the name.

Comment: yes but when I do that the simbolink link still doesn't work. I have done it from the environment and still the same and I can't import it from /usr/local because of the permissions. I don't now how to give PyCharm permissions for accessing the path

Comment: Did you try downloading the library for this environment from the project interpretor settings (The plus sign)

Comment: That worked but is it using the same library as mine or has it installed opencv again? Because my library is manually compiled cause I need the complete version (the one that is in pip or conda isn't the full library) This is the tutorial that I followed https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/28/ubuntu-18-04-how-to-install-opencv/

Comment: How about installing any dependencies in the virtual environment by using the terminal provided by PyCharm on the bottom panel. Any missing libraries which show up can be installed using pip in the terminal for the virtual environment in PyCharm. That ought to do it.

Comment: Yes, if I install all the depencies again and all it will work, but the problem is that it is working fine with other IDE and I don't want to install everything twice. Thanks for your replies